# Cannot use object of type lang as array

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system, admin

I found a free PHP admin system script online which I have setup but can not get working.

I keep getting this error "Cannot use object of type lang as array"

and i'm not sure what this means.

The line of code that the error is on is part of a class which is here:

```
class lang {

        public function __construct( $lang = false, $URL = '' ) {

        }

        private function storeAllowedLanguages() {
        }

        private function setLanguage($lang) {
        }

        public static function createButtons($ismobile) {
        }

        public static function translate($key, $ucfirst=false) {
            if( !isset($_SESSION['LANG']) ) {
                $DB = new db;
                $sql = '
                    SELECT `key`, `value`
                    FROM `_adminlang`
                    WHERE `lang` = "en"
                ';
                $res = $DB->fetch( $sql );
                foreach($res as $rec) {
                    $_SESSION['LANG'][$rec['key']] = $rec['value'];
                }
            }
            return isset($_SESSION['LANG'][$key]) ? $_SESSION['LANG'][$key] : ucfirst(str_replace('_', ' ', strtolower($key)));
        }


    }
```

and the actual line is :

```
    return isset($_SESSION['LANG'][$key]) ? $_SESSION['LANG'][$key] : ucfirst(str_replace('_', ' ', strtolower($key)));
```

could someone help me out with this error please im very stuck

Comment: use `print_r( $_SESSION['LANG'] )` and post the result here

Comment: It prints "lang Object ( )" all over the screen where ever there is content

Comment: Try changing `$_SESSION['LANG'][$key]` to `$_SESSION['LANG']->$key`

Comment: so you must use `$_SESSION['LANG']->{$key}` instead of `$_SESSION['LANG'][$key]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$_SESSION['LANG'] is most likely a object.. try

```
$_SESSION['LANG']->$key
```